# Twitter OAuth Strategy Access Level & Email Problem

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth, passport-twitter

I have a Twitter OAuth strategy like this:

```
consumerKey: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
consumerSecret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
userProfileURL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true",
requestTokenURL: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?x_auth_access_type=read',
callbackURL: '/dashboard/auth/callback',
proxy: true
```

Now, here whenever I include `requestTokenURL: 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?x_auth_access_type=read'`, I am not able to access the user's email. If I remove it, I am able to access the email via `userProfileURL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true"`.

I have enabled the request email permission in the developer dashboard. What am I missing? I am using the [passport-twitter](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/) library for this.

Comment: if this is preventing you from requesting email information and that is important to you, why are you still including the`x_auth_access_type`? I do not remember if the two parameters conflict, but it would not surprise me; the email parameter was added in ~2015 but the access parameter was from ~2012 so they may not be compatible.

Comment: Hey @AndyPiper, I actually want the email without the write access. I want the email with read-only access. If I change it in the developers portal to work on read-only, my bot cannot work. Hence, x_auth_access_type is needed for my users for whom I want email with read-only access.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this does not seem possible.

> Unfortunately the initial x_auth_access_type setting was created at a point long before the email permission was added, and has only ever allowed one or other of the read or write values to be specified. I think what you’re seeing here is that using that parameter does perform an absolute override on what you have configured on the app settings. I’ll note this as something we should improve in the future, but at the moment I can’t say when or if we’re likely to change that behaviour.

Source: https://twittercommunity.com/t/email-is-not-requested-when-x-auth-access-type-parameter-added/72396/5

Comment: Wow, it's been more than five years now & still no update.